# how to share a text string by UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, text, share

we can use UIDocumentInteractionController to share a file to other apps like this:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"test.txt" ofType: nil]];
UIDocumentInteractionController *dic = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: url] retain];
[dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: CGRectZero inView: self.view animated: YES];
```

but how to share a text string(not a text file) by UIDocumentInteractionController?
Android Device can do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is for documents. It is even in the name.

A solution would be to save the string to text file and share that file, or if you want to share a string, for example to post on a social network you should use [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)